# How to remove blank values from a sub hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

```
h = { "name"=>"test", "address"=>"test address", "phone"=>"", 
      "users_attributes"=>{
        "0"=>{"id"=>"26", "email"=>"test@example.com",
              "password"=>"", "password_confirmation"=>""
        }
      }
    }
```

I want to remove `"password"=>"", "password_confirmation"=>""` from this hash

I tried this:

```
sanitize_params = Proc.new do |k, v|
  v.delete_if(&sanitize_params) if v.kind_of?(Hash)
  v.empty?
end
h.delete_if &sanitize_params
```

I don't want to remove values in the first level (i.e I don't want to remove `"phone"=>""`.). But it is removing all blank values.

How is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that with recursion for any number of levels of nesting:

```
def purge_empties(h, top_level=true)
  h.each_with_object({}) do |(k,v),g|
    case v
    when Hash
      g[k] = purge_empties(v, false)
    else
      g[k] = v if top_level || !v.empty?
    end
  end
end

h = { "name"=>"test", "address"=>"test address", "phone"=>"", 
      "users_attributes"=>{
        "0"=>{"id"=>"26", "email"=>"test@example.com",
              "password"=>"", "password_confirmation"=>"",
              "one_more_level"=>{ "cat"=>"meow", "dog"=>"" }
        }
      }
    }

purge_empties(h)
  #=> { "name"=>"test", "address"=>"test address", "phone"=>"",
  #     "users_attributes"=>{
  #       "0"=>{
  #         "id"=>"26", "email"=>"test@example.com",
  #         "one_more_level"=>{"cat"=>"meow"}
  #       }
  #     }
  #   }
```

Comment: I want to remove all blank values except the first level. Hope it is clear.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
h['users_attributes']['0'].delete("password") &&
    h['users_attributes']['0'].delete("password_confirmation")
```

or more globally

```
h['users_attributes']['0'].delete_if {|key, value| value.empty? }
```